# Receving POST request at Node JS Server from Dart gives JSON string with empty value and

Tags: node.js, dart, networking

This is my code at dart side. I have created an object and tried to send the object as request body using `jsonEncode` method.

```
class RZPOrder {
  final int orderId;
  final int amount;

  RZPOrder({this.orderId, this.amount});

  Map toJson() => {'orderId': orderId, 'amount': amount};
}

String url = 'http://876b98959b91.ngrok.io';
print(jsonEncode(order));
final http.Response res = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(order),
);
```

The print statement output here is
`{"orderId":842,"amount":3500}`

On the Node Server side the code is

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.route('/')

.post(function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var options = {
        amount: req.body.amount,
        receipt: req.body.orderId
      };
});
```

The print statement here is `{ '{"orderId":555,"amount":3500}': '' }`

While using the postman, I am getting the same output as in dart.

Please help me in getting the correct json string on the node side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the  `Content-Type` as `'application/json'` on dart side and `app.use(bodyParser.json());` on node side solves the problem.

But, still I am not able to figure out why the json string was changed on node side while using `x-www-form-urlencoded`.